# How do I check see a newline character with my scanner if I'm using a delimiter?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to make an undirected graph with some of the nodes (not all, unlike my example) being connected to one another.  So my input format will look like

```
3
1:2,3
2:1,3
3:1,2
```

Meaning there's three nodes in all, and 1 is connected to 2 and 3, 2 is connected to 1 and 3 and so on.

However, I cannot understand how to take the input in a meaningful way.  Here's what I've got so far.

```
public Graph createGraph() {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("[:|,|\\n]");
    int graphSize = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println(graphSize);
    for (int i = 0; i < graphSize; i++) {
        while (!scan.hasNext("\\n")) {
            System.out.println("Scanned: " + scan.nextInt());
        }
    }
    return new Graph(graphSize);

}
```

Can my

```
while (!scan.hasNext("\\n"))
```

see the newline character when I'm using a delimiter on it?

Comment: delimiters are used to split the string in tokens and are lost in the process. If a token is meaningful to you, you shouldn't use it as a delimiter

Comment: I've tried that, but the first number doesn't get inputted if I leave the newline out of the delimiter

Comment: are you expecting a newline character as part of your input itself?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  If I leave the newline character out of the delimiter then my very first number (the 3) never gets picked up because there's nothing separating it from the 1 on the next line.

Answer (score 0):

yup, scanner can definitely detect new line. infact you dont even have to explicitly specify it. just use

```
scan.hasNextLine()
```

which essentially keeps going as long as there are lines in your input

**Edit**

Why dont you read everything first and then use your for loop?

Comment: Yea I know that, but I want the while loop to end after every new line, not to keep going until I end the input.

Comment: umm, so you want the while loop to end after every line? then how would you parse the remaining lines if the loop ended after the first line?

Comment: My while loop is inside of a for loop that iterates for however many nodes there are, so when the while loop ends, the for loop will loop again until all the nodes are accounted for.

Comment: hmm so you want to read one line, do some processing and then pick up from where you left? would it not be better to just read everything first and then iterate your for loop? for example just store everything in a List of Strings. and then iterate over that list? are you getting the input from a file or from console?

Comment: I will eventually make it so my input will come from either.  But for testing purposes I'm just inputting into the standard input.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you shouldn't be using those delimiters if they are meaningful tokens. In the second line for example, the first integer doesn't have the same meaning as the others, so the `:` is meaningful and should be scanned, even if only to be discarded later. `,` however doesn't change the meaning of the tokens that are separated by it, so it's safe to use as a delimiter : you can grab integers as long as they are delimited by `,`, they still have the same meaning.

So in conclusion, I would use `,` as a delimiter and check manually for `\n`and `:` so I can adapt my code behaviour when I encounter them.

Answer (score 0):

Alright I figured it out.  It's not the prettiest code I've ever written, but it gets the job done.

```
public Graph createGraph() {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    number = scan.nextLine();
    graphSize = Integer.valueOf(number);
    System.out.println(graphSize);
    for (int i = 0; i < graphSize; i++) {
        number = scan.nextLine();
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(number).useDelimiter(",|:");
        while (reader.hasNextByte()) {
            System.out.println("Scanned: " + reader.nextInt());
        }
    }
    return new Graph(graphSize);

}
```